# Can structured types or composite attributes within a structured type be UNIQUE?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, constraints, unique

Can structured types or composite attributes within a structured type be UNIQUE?

For example, is this possible:

```sql
CREATE TYPE testType AS OBJECT (
  attr1 INTEGER,
  attr2 VARCHAR2(20),
  attr3 VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Structured Types or Composite Attributes within a Structured Type be UNIQUE?

No, the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034) does not allow that.

However, if you are using them in an object derived table that is when you can make columns (derived from the object attributes) unique.

```sql
CREATE TYPE testType AS OBJECT (
  attr1 INTEGER,
  attr2 VARCHAR2(20),
  attr3 VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE test_table OF testType(
  attr3 CONSTRAINT test_table__attr3__u UNIQUE
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (attr1, attr2, attr3 ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 );
INSERT INTO test_table (attr1, attr2, attr3 ) VALUES ( 4, 5, 3 );
```

Gives the error:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.TEST_TABLE__ATTR3__U) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54d6677e177c38fdb8c5530103a0de25)*